# Two circle on android AVD screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

There is two circle on screen every time i long click on screen. i have no idea what is this?
is it possible to disable this?
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a workaround : `Setting->General->send keyboard shortcuts to -> vritual device` solved the issue

Comment: this post is not about requesting clarification. it is a workaround

Comment: I suggest putting this comment into the answer. Imo it is an important information that this is a workaround.

Answer (score 13):

[Zoom Icon on the virtual device menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbeEm.png)

I had the same problem when the green circles appear and won't go away I just pressed the zoom button on the Virtual device menu the appears next to the device so you just need to enter the zoom mode then exit and the glitch is gone

Comment: A similar workaround is to rotate the Android screen: `Ctrl+Left Arrow` and the glitch is gone. Then press `Ctrl+Right Arrow` to rotate the screen back.

Answer (score 4):

This is the multi-touch functionality.

Use <kbd>F1</kbd> to see the setting in emulator

[image: emulator help]

Comment: thanks, but mine it is activated without the need to hold CTRL.it is activated just by a long click.and is really annoying.is there any way to disable that?

Comment: check settings if there is another key combination or it may be a bug,see if it is every emulator or just one, if a emulator image is corrupt, delete it. make sure emulator is updated

Comment: I'm running android studio 3.4.2 and having two virtual devices "Nexus 5x API 24" and "Nexus 9 API 28". I have the issue with both of them.every time i need to pull down device notification bar , multi-touch tow circles appears

Comment: never saw the issue before. create new device and see if it has the issue

Answer (score 2):

For me it seems the problem is with Desktop app.
I am using Linux Mint and after clicking on `Ctrl-Alt-F1` the stacked multi-touch was gone.

Comment: you mean each time mulitoch get activated,you click `Ctrl-Alt-F1`? or just one time using this shortkey would disable multitoch?

Comment: just one time would disable it. for me it looks like it is some bug.